# OracleConnection.Open() not working in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have a VC# application that tries to open an Oracle database, but when it calls OracleConnection.Open(), it throws, "Attempted to read or write protected memory."

Here is the stack trace of the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsCon.Open1(IntPtr& opsConCtx, IntPtr& opsErrCtx, OpoConValCtx* pOpoConValCtx, OpoConRefCtx& pOpoConRefCtx)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsCon.Open(IntPtr& opsConCtx, IntPtr& opsErrCtx, OpoConValCtx* pOpoConValCtx, OpoConRefCtx& pOpoConRefCtx)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.ConnectionDispenser.CreateConnectionPool(OpoConCtx& opoConCtx)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.ConnectionDispenser.GetConnectionPool(OpoConCtx& opoConCtx, Boolean& bConObtained)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.ConnectionDispenser.Open(OpoConCtx opoConCtx, Int32 enlistAttrVal, Boolean& bGotEnlistedConnection)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnectionOCP.Open(OracleConnection con)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at GenericOracleLogin.frmMain.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
in C:\VS\Workspaces\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GenericOracleLogin\GenericOracleLogin\Form1.cs:line 56
```

Here is the relevant portion of the C# code:

```
        OracleConnectionStringBuilder ConnString = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
        ConnString.DataSource = txtDataSource.Text;
        ConnString.UserID = txtUsername.Text;
        ConnString.Password = txtPassword.Text;
        String ConnectionString = ConnString.ToString();

        Conn = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString);
        Conn.Open();
```

The exception is thrown at Conn.Open()

I am using Oracle.DataAccess version 4.122.1.0; it is a 64-bit version running on a 64-bit app

Two things to note:

First, this is being done after Oracle was uninstalled and then reinstalled into a different directory. I can't find any references to "oracle.dataaccess" in any of the GAC directories. I also don't see any BindingRedirects in any readable machine.config files.

Second, when I use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess in place of Oracle.DataAccess, the code works.

I assume that the problem is, it is not using the specific version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll that I want it to use. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you install an Oracle Client? Is it the same version as loaded Oracle.DataAccess.dll? Check which DLL is actually loaded with `con.GetType().Assembly.Location`

Comment: The DLL was in the location I expected it to be. However, see below for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that, while my main Oracle odp.net directory had Oracle.DataAccess.dll version 4.122.1.20161216, which is what I was using, my Oracle Data Toold odp.net directory had version 4.122.1.20170524. When I used the newer version, the app ran successfully.

Comment: Yes, version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll has to match **exactly** the version of the Oracle client.